# How to execute insert query on deploy of java ee application?

Tags: java, sql

I have a java ee application with a web application and ejb module. There is some tables I want to be populated automatically when deployed. I have the entities set up and the sql file with the queries to be executed.

I feel it may be something to do with the persistence.xml file but not sure what to include. So, how do I get my server(wildfly) to execute the sql queries on deploy, similar to the way that you can specify the persistence.xml to drop and create as the table generation strategy.

If it makes a difference, I am using postgres for my database provider, java ee 7 and wildfly 8.2.0.Final for my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I was looking for was like this, it belongs in the persistence.xml properties section.

`<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/data.sql" />`

[Database Schema Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm) This link is useful for such techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a class extends from ServletContextListener which calls your method from the contextInitialized() method. You attach the listener to your webapp in web.xml, e.g.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.packages.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

ServletListener code:

```
package com.packages;

public class Listener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContext context) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring JDBC DataSource initializer feature or Instead of configuring DataSourceInitializer, you can use spring’s custom element jdbc:initialize-database element where jdbcnamespace xmlns:jdbc is set to http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc. You just need to point attribute data-source to the DataSource bean and configure the scripts using the child element jdbc:script and location attribute. For example, we can achieve the same result using the below configuration:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="true">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-load-data.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you could use a servlet ContextListener to populate the database upon context start.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

I've done such a trick for prototype applications in the past; just make sure to check if data doesn't already exist to prevent populating the database with duplicate data upon redeployments.

A rough example:

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){

    // create manually, inject, whatever you're using
    EntityManager em = ...;

    Number cnt = (Number) em.createQuery("select count(d) from Data d").getSingleResult();

    if(cnt.intValue() == 0){
      insertFixtureData(em);
    }
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce){
  }

  private void insertFixtureData(EntityManager em){
    // insert data
  }
}
```